# Link to OneNote Notebook from SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, list, onenote

Is there a way to add a link in a SharePoint list item, that refers to a certain section or page, or even better, a document embedded on a page, in a OneNote notebook that resides in a document library on a different SharePoint site?

I want to send an Outlook mail item, with an attachment, to the Notebook on my SharePoint site, then link to it from a list item on a different SharePoint site.

We're on SP 2013.  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

On this page: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-hyperlinks-to-pages-sections-and-notebooks-35a2c5e3-87fd-400a-a4f5-ef82e778c208#bm2

Microsoft says you can copy a hyperlink to a section of OneNote by right clicking on the section and selecting the option to do so.  Mine said "copy link to paragraph".  When I pasted it into the field of a Links List on a SharePoint site, I got an error.  There was " onenote: " on the front of the link.  Once I deleted that, it worked perfectly.

note: User must have access to that shared OneNote file for it to work and they may have to reenter credentials.